# pk_set in m2m_changed signal for post_add action contains all related items

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-orm

When the model's ManyToMany field is updated and a m2m_changed signal is sent I am getting every item, **previously related and new items**, for that relationship in the pk_set argument. Is this the correct behavior? I was expecting only the new item or multiple items that were added to the relationship to be present in the pk_set.

If that is the expected behavior, is there a better way to get only the **new** items being added to the relationship other than using the post_add signal and comparing the list of items already associated with the model with the incoming list?

**Edit:** It appears there are no items related to the ManyToMany field in pre_add, then all of the items are there on post_add.

**Edit 2:** Ok, so the many to many relationship is getting cleared before the list of items is added, receiving the pre_clear and post_clear actions. Not sure how I am supposed to get a diff of how the set of items has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a better spot to do this comparison is in the model's admin in save_model(). There I can get the original object and the form being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Until Django 1.9, setting objects on an m2m field through direct assignment would call `clear` and then `add`.

This is likely the behaviour you were observing.  As of Django 1.9, only differences are processed.

If you need the old behaviour, you can pass `clear=True` to the `set` method on the related manager.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#related-set-direct-assignment